# Adding python internal modules (cgi.py) to yocto image

Tags: yocto

I am trying to add some python libraries to my custom image.
So far, I successfully added some libraries.

Some others, like *sqlalchemy*, was requiring some python internal module named *“dummy_threading”* and thus producing some error output stating "No module named ‘dummy_threading’ ".
I found out you can solve this issue by adding *‘python-threading’* to the image.

Unfortunately, I came across a similar issue with the *‘python-requests’* library, which cannot be imported throwing 'No module named ‘cgi’ ".

cgi.py seems to be a python internal module, much like *‘dummy_threading’*, but I can’t find a way to include it to my image.
I already tried to add 'python-cgi' with no success.

Does anyone have a solution to this ?

Lucas

Additionnal info:
Yocto 1.7 (I cannot upgrade it to the newest)
Python 2.7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite [poky already contains](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-devtools/python) maybe all what you need regarding python, as you mention, there are some internal parts of python which are provided in a different way.

A good idea to find out how to get what you miss is to inspect the manifest files. Such files can be found in your layers (basically poky and openembedded-core). For example, in poky is located in:

```
poky/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python-x.y-manifest.inc
```

If I check inside mine [I can see](https://github.com/dlespiau/poky/blob/9eea1ebe3e4b27529780dfafaf424d373bfb2867/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python-2.7-manifest.inc#L163):

```
FILES_${PN}-netserver="${libdir}/python2.7/cgi.* ${libdir}/python2.7/*HTTPServer.* ${libdir}/python2.7/SocketServer.* "
```

Notice the *cgi.* and the *FILES_${PN}-netserver*.

Finally that would mean that the package you need is actually **"python-netserver"**.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for, thanks a lot !